# How we write trigger on campaignMember, When we added any contact A into the campaignMember

Tags: trigger, account, contact, campaign

How we write a trigger on campaignMember. When we added any contact A into the campaign member. I need to add all contact into the campaign member who is associated with the account of contact A.

Here is my code

```java
trigger AddContacttoCampaignMember on CampaignMember (before insert) {

    List <CampaignMember> lstCampa = new List<CampaignMember>();
    List <CampaignMember> lstCampa1 = new List<CampaignMember>();
    CampaignMember camp1 = new CampaignMember();
    ID conid ;
    ID campId;
    ID CamapignId;
    String status1;
    lstCampa = [select Id,CampaignId, ContactId from CampaignMember where Id =: Trigger.new];

    for(CampaignMember con : lstCampa)
    {
        conid = con.ContactId;  
        campId = con.Id;
        CamapignId = con.CampaignId;
        //status1 = con.Status['sent'];
    }
    List<Contact> conlst = new List<Contact>();
    conlst = [select AccountId from Contact where Id =: conid];
    Id accid;
    for(Contact con1 :conlst)
    {
        accid = con1.AccountId;
    }

    List <Contact> conlist1 = new List<Contact>();
    conlist1 = [select Id from Contact where AccountId =:accid];

    for(Contact con2 :conlist1)
    {
        camp1.id = campId;
        camp1.ContactId = con2.Id;
        camp1.CampaignId = CamapignId;
        camp1.status = 'Sent';
        lstCampa1.add(camp1);
    }

    insert lstCampa1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. We cannot implement your requirements or provide complete designs, but we're happy to help you with issues you encounter in your own implementation process. For more about our format, please take the [Tour] and read [ask]. Please [edit] your question to show us *what you've tried* and *where you are stuck*.

Comment: If you're just getting started, Trailhead provides a comprehensive [module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers) on writing Apex triggers.

Comment: I had written trigger but , it is not working

Comment: **Please edit your question to show us what you've tried and where you are stuck.**

Comment: It is frustrating to tell someone something multiple times. You've provided your code (which I've formatted for you. Being consistent with braces, indentation, spacing, and blank lines helps make it easier to read your code), but you still haven't told us _where you're stuck_. "It's not working" is not a helpful statement because we don't know _how_ it's supposed to work unless you tell us. For now, I've downvoted this question.

Answer (score 1):

This trigger needs to be **bulkified** to use collections throughout. There is a [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) on how to write bulk Apex triggers, as well as extensive material here on SFSE (try searching "bulkification"). It also misses the mark by repeatedly using incorrect idioms for basic Apex operations and data structures.

I'll highlight a few of the specific problems in this trigger that are leading it not to work as expected. In the future, please make sure to always include a **problem statement** in your question that specifies exactly what is intended and what the current behavior or error is.

```
lstCampa = [select Id,CampaignId, ContactId from CampaignMember where Id =: Trigger.new];
```

You do not need to query for records that are being modified in the trigger. They are already available to you in `Trigger.new`. Further, since this is a `before insert` trigger, the records cannot be queried because they *haven't been inserted yet*.

```
for(CampaignMember con : lstCampa)
{
    conid = con.ContactId;  
    campId = con.Id;
    CamapignId = con.CampaignId;
    //status1 = con.Status['sent'];
}
```

This loop populates `conid`, `campId`, and `CamapignId` (misspelling) with the values from the *last* `CampaignMember` in the trigger's invocation, which might contain up to 200 entries. This will do the wrong thing if multiple records are being updated in a single operation. This needs to be bulkified.

```
List<Contact> conlst = new List<Contact>();
```

You don't need to initialize a list to which you're going to assign another list, a query result.

```
conlst = [select AccountId from Contact where Id =: conid];
Id accid;
for(Contact con1 :conlst)
{
    accid = con1.AccountId;
}
```

This is the same incorrect pattern as above. Additionally, it is not bulkified for queries, and will fail if more than one CampaignMember is created in the same operation.

```
for(Contact con2 :conlist1)
{
    camp1.id = campId;
    camp1.ContactId = con2.Id;
    camp1.CampaignId = CamapignId;
    camp1.status = 'Sent';
    lstCampa1.add(camp1);
}

insert lstCampa1;
```

You're mutating and accumulating the same `CampaignMember` instance, `camp1` over and over again. You need to create a *new* instance each time through the loop if you want to create multiple records.